# How to remove all elements in a list that appear more than once

Tags: python, list

My question is different from removing duplicate

## removing duplicate:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 7]
```

will become
**you only keep one of the duplicated values**

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```

## My Question:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 7]
```

will become
**you don't keep any of the duplicated values**

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 7]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will work:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 7]
res = [i for i in list_1 if list_1.count(i) == 1]

>>>print(res)
[1, 2, 7]
```

Comment: this is very inefficient and should be avoided

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for x in list_1:
    d[x] += 1
res = [k for k,v in d if v == 1]
```

complexity: O(n)

EDITED. Even shorter for the same complexity

```
from collections import Counter
res = [k for k,v in Counter(list_1).items() if v == 1]
```

Comment: This will not work properly if there are items that occur 3,5,7,etc times. With the given input list, it returns {1, 2, 3, 7} which is incorrect as 3 is found 3 times

Comment: @IoaTzimas You're right, I edited

Comment: You should use a `collections.Counter`